# cannot add my slidemenu to my mainfile css/html

Tags: html, css, web

i made a slidermenu, but i failed some stuff. I dont know how to make it sticky. but the biggest problem is that it looks wheird when i add it to my main file. it works fine when i run the slidebar on a clear page but when i implemnt it into this file it looks crazy. the sysmbols r not infront of the text anymore.
can anyone tell me how i can add the slidermenu to this file right

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="../js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesearch.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="../images/logo.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/slidebar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background-box" onclick="tag()"></div>
        <div class="container" id="tag-box">
            <div><a class="close-box" onclick="tag(), getValue()">&times;</a></div>
            <br>Selectable Tags:</br>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <script src="../js/slidebar.js"></script>
            <a href = "#"><img class="image-size"  src="../images/logo.png"></a>
            <div class="bars"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x" id="scale" onclick="slidebar()"></i></div>    
            <a><img class="image-size" src="../images/menu.png" onclick=""></a>
            <button id="btnabout" onclick="tag()">Tags</button>
            <div class="search_box"><input type="text" name="box" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by name" class="form-control" /></div>
            <div id="background-boxtitle" onclick="tag()"></div>            
        </nav>
        <section class="sec1">
            <div class="slidebar" id="slidebar"><?php include '../db/slidebar.php'; echo $slidebarbutton;?></div>
        </section>
        <section class="sec2">
            <script src="../js/search.js"></script>
            <div id="result"></div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </section>
        <section class="sec3">
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
:root {
  --slidermenu-color: #303030;
 }
#slidebar{
    position:absolute;
    left:-15%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .5s;
    background: var(--slidermenu-color);
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
#slidebar.active{
  left: 0%;
}
#slidebarlock{
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  transition: .5s;
}
#slidebarlock.active{
  left: 15%;
}
.slidebarbutton {
      background-color: #303030;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      text-align: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 20px 0px;
      width: 100%;
      }
.slidebarbutton:hover{
    background-color: #494949;
}
.bars:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slidebarbutton div i{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right: 40px; 
}

#slidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

#slidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--slidermenu-color);
}

#slidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}

#slidebar:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: black;
  opacity: .8;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #222;;
}
header{
    padding: 10px 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
section.sec1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
div.gallery:hover {
    border: 2px solid #404040;
    background: #404040;
}
div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    float: left;
    width: 215px;
    height: 400px;
    color: #fff;
}


div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
section.sec3{
    padding: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: auto;
}
section.sec3 h2{
    font-size: 3em;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background: url(../images/bg1.jpg);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
nav ul{
    display: flex;
}
.image-size{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 1%;
    height: 40px;
}
.search_box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-150%, -50%);
    height: 20px;
}

.search_box input[type="text"]{
  width: 300%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.fa-search{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px){
  .search_box{
    width: 95%;
  }
}
#tag-box{
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
#tag-box.active{
  top: 25%;
}
.container{
    max-width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div{
    margin: 5px;
}
.container div a{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container div a:hover{
    color: #f00;
}
.container div label{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container div label input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: none;
}
.container div label span{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #424242;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: 555;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid #FFA500;
}
.container div label span:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%
}
.container div label input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span{
    background: #FFA500;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #FFA500;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 15px #FFA500;
}


 #background-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
#background-box.active{
  top: 0%;
}
#background-boxtitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -120%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
#background-boxtitle.active{
  top: 0%;
}
#scale{
    transition: .5s;
    color:white;
    transform: translate(22px, 16px);
}
#scale.active{
    transition: .5s;
    transform: translate(22px, 16px) rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: What means 'looking weird'? Is your sliderbar created by PHP or by JavaScript? We should see, what codes this actually implements (although I guess it is done by PHP). Also why do you put <script> tag inside <nav>? ... Scripts should be put inside header or at the end of the body. If they are in header, it should be triggered by onload event on window or document.

Comment: no it is working fine with the clear file. it is looking like this: https://prnt.sc/so2wif

Comment: Well, in your code there is no such text as 'search' or 'video', there is actually no HTML code of your search bar. If you want help, we must be able to reproduce the same error as you have - otherwise we can only wish you luck.